# Problem with printing and sleeping in for loop with end key word argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, printing, keyword-argument

When I write the following code into python file/console:

```py
import time, os

string = "what am I saying right now?"
for x in string:
    print(x)
    time.sleep(.1)
```

**Output:**

```
w
h
a
t
 
a
m
 
I
 
s
a
y
i
n
g
 
r
i
g
h
t
 
n
o
w
?
```

everything works as expected

---

However, when I add pass in anything to the `end` keyword argument it still works, but it does `time.sleep(.1)` methods before printing it out.

```py
import time, os

string = "what am I saying right now?"
for x in string:
    print(x, end="")
    time.sleep(.1)
```

```
around 2.7 seconds later:
```

**Output:**

```
what am I saying right now?
```

**There are a few issues with this:**

- The print statement is displayed after the whole loop is run (meaning the longer the string the longer it takes for the string to get printed out
- There is no "cool" scrolling effect that is gotten from adding the sleep method after the print statement making it useless

---

if anyone knows why this happens and how I could mitigate this in the future that would be greatly appreciated.

**Thanks in advance!!!**

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `flush=True` argument to print. Using empty char for `end` means there are no newlines in the output so line-buffered output will not write to terminal unless forced to by the flush